# Spring, REST, Jackson and cyclic hierarchy

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Suppose I have the following entity hierarchy

```
class Parent {
  Long id;
  List<Child> children;
}
```

and

```
class Child {
  Long id;
  Parent parent;
}
```

I want to be able to make two types of REST request:

1. /parents/1 that should return:

   ```
   {
    "id": "1",
    "children": [{"id": 1, /* probably some other fields */}]
   }
   ```
2. /children/1

   ```
   {
    "id": "1",
    "parent": {"id": 1, /* some other fields */}
   }
   ```

What is the best way or best practice to return such type of views of the domain objects using Spring and Jackson.

Currently I have figured out two options:

1. To use custom @JsonView(WithParent), @JsonView(WithChild)
2. Use DTO approach